# SWF "loading" icon in a flex combobox drop down

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

In the flex web app i'm working on, i need to show a loading icon (an SWF spinner) in the combobox drop down until the user list is initialized.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What version of Flex do you using? 3.x or 4.x?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend ComboBox, suppress dropdown appearance if data not ready, and show some replacement of dropdown with animation. When data is ready, set it into dataProvider and open dropdown programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

showBusyCursor = true when the data starts to load.
showBusyCursor = false when you are done getting the data.

Comment: Of course it is. As a matter of fact I am using it right now on a project

Comment: Actually, let me clarify the showBusyCursor code will go on the HTTPService object not on the combo box.